# Command line tool to convert xls/xlsx to xml?

Tags: xml, excel, xls, xlsx, file-conversion

Is there there an open source command line tool that will convert xls/xlsx to xml? Ideally I'd like to do this on an *NIX system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XLSX is easy, the format is a zip file.  Within the zip there's a "worksheets" folder in "xl" that has an xml file for the data in each sheet.  If you unzip you can access the xml directly.

XLS I'm not sure.

Jesse

Answer (score 0):

happened to be using ruby to automate some excel operations, including save as xml.

but this requires `win32OLE` and will not be on *nix.